# Are the *.cod files in OTAInstall folder signed, too?

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

OK, I'm confused about what .cod files get signed (StandardInstall and/or OTAInstall folder). I am using BlackBerry WebWorks 2.2 with PhoneGap 1.0, and just learned that the .cod file in the StandardInstall folder is really just an archival of several *.cod files.

My project folder: C:\Blackberry\MyProject

If I use the command...

`C:\Blackberry\MyProject>ant load-device`

...does it sign the MyProject.cod file in StandardInstall folder and all the *.cod files in OTAInstall folder?

Also, if I use the command...

`C:\Blackberry\MyProject>ant build`

...then use the SignatureTool via command line to sign the .cod file in the StandardInstall folder...

`C:\Blackberry\MyProject\build\StandardInstall>java -jar c:\bbwp\bin\SignatureTool.jar MyProject.cod`

...will it also sign the .cod files in the OTAInstall folder?

My suspicion is that I need to also sign the *.cod files in the OTAInstall folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SOF adnd Good Luck! :)

You must include all the cod files from OTA folder using the signature jar (start the jar and then in the ui add the .cod  files) as said in[0]:

**Resume:**

1. Select the cod files
2. On the BlackBerry Signature Tool menu, click Request.
3. In the dialog box, type your private key password, then click OK. 
   The BlackBerry Signature Tool uses the private key password to append the signature to the request, and sends the signature list of .cod files for verification.
4. Check the Status column. 
   For files that are signed, the Status column contains Signed. For files that are not signed, the Status column 
   contains Failed. A .cod file might be rejected because you typed an incorrect private key password.

[0]
http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/8067/645045/8655/8656/1271077/BlackBerry_Signature_Tool_Developer_Guide.pdf?nodeid=1271325&vernum=0

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the directions for using the BlackBerry Signature Tool.  I guess my question was more about the ANT scripts provided by PhoneGap.  Based on my trial and error, using the ANT script: 'load-device', this will compile the app and then invoke the Signature Tool on the .cod files first.  So, all the .cod files in the /OTAInstall folder were signed.